# How to remove podcast from home lock screen?

Tags: podcasts

Is it possible to turn the podcast home screen to off?
Currently if I lock my phone, the last podcast I was listening to is displaying and if I accidently press the start button it turns on.

I don't want this visible on my lock screen.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Do you wish to remove it while still listening the podcast or after it has finished?

Comment: if I lock my screen, I want it removed from the lock screen.

Comment: As long as the audio playback is in progress, the widget remains on the lock screen. To remove it completely, you'll need to quit the Podcast app from the multitasking UI.